# Coalescing rows from boolean mask

Tags: numpy

I have a 2D array and a boolean mask of the same size. I want to use the mask to coalesce consecutive rows in the 2D array: By coalesce I mean to reduce the rows by taking the first occurrence. An example:

```
rows = np.r_['1,2,0', :6, :6]
mask = np.tile([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], (2,1)).T.astype(bool)
```

Expected output:

```
array([[0, 0],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 4])
```

And to illustrate how the output might be obtained:

```
array([[0, 0],                        array([[0, 0],                         array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],                               [0, 0],                                [2, 2],
       [2, 2],      -> select ->             [2, 2],        -> reduce ->            [3, 3],
       [3, 3],                               [3, 3],                                [4, 4]])
       [4, 4],                               [4, 4],    
       [5, 5]])                              [4, 4]])
```

What I have tried:

```
rows[~mask].reshape(-1,2)
```

But this will only select the rows which should not be reduced.

Comment: Can you explain the "select" step in your illustration? In particular, it's unclear to me how `mask` comes into play here.

Comment: The regions with ```True``` in the mask should be coalesced.

Comment: It's basically a forward fill with rows inside the mask.

Comment: @Kevin Hi, I realized in my answer that the the process could be done way more efficient. I have updated my answer now, you ought to check it out. The code is also much simpler.

Comment: @NaphatAmundsen Thanks, it's a very good solution!

Comment: Do you think it is possible to negate the leading ones using one boolean operation? ```np.diff``` is essentially just doing ```mask[1:] - mask[:1]``` with the ```prepend``` concatenation. Subtraction works but it is not tailored for boolean values. I was thinking something like ```mask[1:] < mask[:1]``` but I am not sure.

Comment: Good point! You could do `mask[1:] = mask[1:] & mask[:-1]` then do `mask[0] = False`. I think this should be faster and more memory efficient since we don't need to allocate memory for the `np.diff` output. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Upgraded answer

I realized that my initial submission did a lot of unnecessary operations, I realized that given mask

```
mask = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0]
```

You simply want to negate the leading ones:

```
#negate:v       v       v 
mask = [0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0]
```

then negate the mask to get your wanted rows. This way is MUCH more efficient than doing a forward fill on indices and removing repeated indices (see old answer). Revised solution:

```
import numpy as np 

rows = np.r_['1,2,0', :6, :6]
mask = np.tile([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], (2,1)).T.astype(bool)

def maskforwardfill(a: np.ndarray, mask: np.ndarray):
    mask = mask.copy()
    mask[1:] = mask[1:] & mask[:-1] # Negate leading True values
    mask[0] = False # First element should always be False, either it is False anyways, or it is a leading True value (which should be set to False)
    return a[~mask] # index out wanted rows

# Reduce mask's dimension since I assume that you only do complete rows
print(maskforwardfill(rows, mask.any(1)))
#[[0 0]
# [2 2]
# [3 3]
# [4 4]]
```

## Old answer

Here I assume that you only need complete rows (like in @Arne's answer). My idea is that given the mask and the corresponding array indices

```
mask =    [1,1,0,0,1,1]
indices = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

you can use `np.diff` to first obtain

```
indices = [0,-1,2,3,4,-1]
```

Then a forward fill (where `-1` acts as `nan`) on the indices such that you get

```
[0,0,2,3,4,4]
```

of which can use `np.unique` to remove repeated indices:

```
[0,2,3,4] # The rows indices you want
```

### Code:

```
import numpy as np 

rows = np.r_['1,2,0', :6, :6]
mask = np.tile([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], (2,1)).T.astype(bool)

def maskforwardfill(a: np.ndarray, mask: np.ndarray):
    mask = mask.copy()
    indices = np.arange(len(a))
    mask[np.diff(mask,prepend=[0]) == 1] = False # set leading True to False
    indices[mask] = -1 
    indices = np.maximum.accumulate(indices) # forward fill indices
    indices = np.unique(indices) # remove repeats
    return a[indices] # index out wanted rows

# Reduce mask's dimension since I assume that you only do complete rows
print(maskforwardfill(rows, mask.any(1)))
#[[0 0]
# [2 2]
# [3 3]
# [4 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's always about complete rows, you can reduce the mask to one dimension. Then a straightforward approach is to iterate over the rows:

```py
# reduce mask to one dimension for row selection
mask_1d = mask.any(axis=1) 

# replace rows with previous ones based on mask
for i in range(1, len(rows)):
    if mask_1d[i-1] and mask_1d[i]:
        rows[i] = rows[i-1]

# leave out repeated rows
reduced = [rows[0]]
for i in range(1, len(rows)):
    if not (rows[i] == rows[i-1]).all():
        reduced.append(rows[i])
        
reduced = np.array(reduced)
reduced
```

```
array([[0, 0],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3],
       [4, 4]])
```